# "Azure DevOps Organization" resource in Azure

Tags: azure, azureportal

I have resource group that is named "VisualStudioOnline-" and inside there is a single resource as given below. Looks like Azure DevOps created it. What is it used for and can I delete it?

[image]

PS: I would need to continue use the DevOps organization and projects.

Comment: You might have created the devops project for CI&CD in the azure, you can go and delete it simply if you dont use.

Comment: No I use the DevOps project.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to https://dev.azure.com/ and delete the organization from there or you could hit the following url and delete it,

```
https://dev.azure.com/{ORGANIZATION_NAME}/_settings/
```

replace **`ORGANIZATION_NAME`** with actual value

Comment: I don't intend to delete DevOps organisation. I would still need it.

Comment: till you delete it it will be existing in azure portal because it is mapped

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can delete it if you want to keep your Azure Devops environment. As far as I know, billing for Azure Devops needs to be linked to a certain Azure subscription, hence the appearance of the organization in your subscription.

**note**

I believe it is possible to **move the organization to another subscription** though (from within Azure Devops UI >> organization settings >> billing >> 'change billing'). This will link the billing for your Devops to the other subscription.

I have never done this myself, but perhaps the resource would then also be moved to the other subscription?

Comment: You cannot link it to a subscription with a spending limit, by the way